# node.js upgrade from v0.12.6

Tags: node.js, upgrade

Currently we are using node.js v0.12.6 in linux and i need to upgrade to the latest version. From the download site https://nodejs.org/en/download/ , I can download node-v4.4.1-linux-x64.tar.

1) Can you please suggest whether i can upgrade from v0.12.6 to v4.4.1 directly?
2) Is there any documents to refer for this upgrade.
3) In the previous releases: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/, i see Vo series of node.js ends with Node.js v0.12.12. so just want to make sure that i am upgrading to the right version.

Thanks
Siva.

Comment: You may want to start with the [blog article for v4.0.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/) as well as the [list of breaking changes between v0.12 and v4](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS/wiki/Breaking-changes-between-v0.12-and-next-LTS-release).

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through several upgrades of Node (starting from 0.4.x and now on 4.x).  As with all runtime upgrades (not just Node) there is no standard procedure.  However the process I outline below should probably help:

On your development and QA machines, use NVM, to start with source(0.12.6) and migrate to target(4.4.1):

1. Install NVM from here: https://github.com/creationix/nvm
2. Go through the instructions to install node 0.12.6, and install all your packages and dependencies.
3. Run your tests and ensure everything is working as expected for your source environment
4. Create and switch to a new branch of your code for 'upgrade'
5. nvm install v4.4.1
6. upgrade each of your npm dependencies manually, commit package.js granularly
7. Run your tests and fix where needed, commit fixes granularly
8. When you are confident, you should have a new branch that works as desired on the new version (4.4.1)
9. Have QA follow their testing procedures on the new 'upgrade' branch
10. Go through a normal test/fix cycle with branch and merge from/to 'upgrade'
11. When everyone is happy, merge upgrade and launch.

Good Luck!